# Excluding some Object fields from serialization

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement annotated object to serialize it into xml string.

```
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
        // Marshal the object to a StringWriter
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "http://www.example.com/schema.xsd");
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(obj, stringWriter);
        result = stringWriter.toString();
```

How to exclude some fields of the object in order not to send them? What annotation that class field has to be annotated in order to exclude it from final string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [@XmlTransient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) annotation:

> Prevents the mapping of a JavaBean property/type to XML representation.

```
@XmlTransient
public String toBeSkippedField;
```

Comment: Please, can you answer similar as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010432/changing-some-object-field-names-during-serialization

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `transient` keyword to omit a field from being serialized.

For example:

```
int k;
transient int j;
```

`Variable j` will not be serialized as we have mentioned the `transient` keyword.

Comment: Please Deserialize and check if the value of the field has been initialised.